# UFW is stopping every day aroung 6:30am

Tags: cron, ufw

We have a bit strange to the server. The UFW will be stopped every morning at 6:25 - 6:30.

There is no specific cron job we do at that time.

This is the log of the syslog:

```
Dec 30 06:25:01 app69 CRON[16653]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Dec 30 06:25:02 app69 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1327" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 30 06:25:30 app69 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-METADATA.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-METADATA.device/start timed out.
Dec 30 06:25:30 app69 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-METADATA.device.
Dec 30 06:25:30 app69 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /var/lib/cloud/seed/config_drive.
Dec 30 06:25:30 app69 systemd[1]: var-lib-cloud-seed-config_drive.mount: Job var-lib-cloud-seed-config_drive.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 30 06:25:30 app69 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-METADATA.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-METADATA.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

At the time, the syslog log file will be rolled out to syslog.1

Comment: What makes you think ufw stopped ?

Comment: I think because of the apf. I just realised that there is apf daily job on the cron.

Comment: apf ????????????

Comment: APF another firewall. Here is some insight for similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302280/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-turns-off-inactive-after-a-while

Comment: Generally I would not run the two together that are both front ends for iptables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302280/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-turns-off-inactive-after-a-while

It is because of the APF (Advance Policy Firewall) that we also install to the machine. It will flush all the firewall configuration.

For now we just stop the apf to start and run at the daily cron job.